# Why Is iOS App Causing Memory Leak in Xcode When Idle?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks

I am writing a game in Swift using SpriteKit with Xcode 7.3 on a Mac mini running El Capitan (both updated in last couple of days).

Shortly after I started, my Mac mini started crashing. The error log indicated that a Kernel Panic had occurred likely due to a memory leak & the process was identified as Xcode. Looking at the Activity Monitor, I can see that when this specific app is loaded in Xcode, the memory used by Xcode fairly rapidly increases even though the App is just sitting there doing nothing.

When other apps are loaded & idle, the memory usage stays more or less constant as you would expect. I have Googled for clues for several hours but can find only info. about memory leaks when an App is running & how to detect them with Instruments.

This is a weird one as far as I'm concerned.  I do not have any idea how to start to figure out what's causing this other than starting with a fresh project & gradually adding code to see if/where it starts happening again.  I would appreciate any ideas other Xcode users may have.

Answer (score 1):

You don't happen to have

```
skView.showPhysics = true
```

turned on? 
That is know to be causing memory issues exactly as you described.

Comment: No. I am not using physics in this app but good to know for future reference. Thx for input.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things you can do to start diagnosing this issue. Firstly you say that only one app is doing this. So this would indicate that the problem is an app problem rather than XCode. This is a good thing :-)

Next I would start using the profiler to monitor the memory and allocated objects in the app. try taking snap shots of the memory at regular intervals and look at what has been allocated since the prior snap shot. The profiler can then help you to dig down into the leaking objects and see where they are being retained and released. This might give you the clue you need.

Another thing is try is the profilers leaks monitoring. That also might tell you whats going on inside your app.

Lastly, is there anything in your code that is executing in some sort of loop. Something that animates on the home screen for example. Perhaps that is leaking.

Comment: Adding to drekka's suggestions, you might find this link helpful. These are Apple's videos covering Instruments from WWDC. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/WWDCVideos.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much to Drekka & Adrian B for your speedy answers but, as always happens, as soon as I post a question, I stumble across some information that leads to an understanding & (in this case partial) solution.  Looking for an answer to a different question, I came across a thread on the Apple Developers Forum where several others are reporting the same issue.

It is related to the use of the SpriteKit Scene Editor.  Hence it is app related in that for me it occurred with the only app for which I have ever used the Scene Editor but in reality it is an Xcode bug.  What happens is that if the Scene Editor window is open (i.e. the .sks file is selected), even if the scene is blank, Xcode starts to leak memory at a rate of about 1MB/sec.  If you close that window, the leakage stops.  It happens even if Xcode is minimized.  Apparently, it has been reported as a bug. I guess the work around for now is to accept the leakage while you're modifying your scene & then close the editor when you've finished (or do everything in code).

Cheers,

RB